# How can I capture the results of this Stored Procedure in a List<>?

Tags: c#, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, linq-to-sql

I have wrestled with this for at least 3 hours, and I am somewhat new to C#, especially with returning multiple rows from a stored procedure in SQL Server.

I would like to return the results of a stored procedure :

```
create procedure ingredientNames_givenDishId
    @dishid inT
AS
    SELECT 
        a.ingredientname --given dish id, return ingredientnames     
    FROM 
        dbo.purple_ingredients a 
    JOIN 
        dbo.purple_dish_ingredients b ON a.ingredientid = b.ingredientid
    WHERE
        b.dishid = @dishid
```

This is the result when I exectute the same procedure in SQL Server, with a 10 as dishid:
[image]

My C# code:

```
private void btnIngs3FromDishId_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    List<Ingredient> someIngs = new List<Ingredient>();

    Purple_DataClasses1DataContext dbContextCreateMenu = 
        new Purple_DataClasses1DataContext(DataHandler.theConnectionString);
    foreach (var row in dbContextCreateMenu.ingredientNames_givenDishId(10))
            MessageBox.Show(row.ToString());
```

I have also tried:

```
     var thing = dbContextCreateMenu.ingredientNames_givenDishId(10);
     var anotherThing = thing.AsEnumerable();
        foreach (var subthing in anotherThing)
```

This last example actually showed the 3 string values when I set a breakpoint and hovered the mouse over "anotherThing":
[image: looks like I could get the data!]

I could drill down with my mouse and see the string values once, then I would 
get a notice on subsequent tries: {"The query results cannot be enumerated more than once."}

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

@Enigmativity: That helped, and very simple to implement. Here is what I ended up with, that works just fine:

```
var thing= dbContextCreateMenu.ingredientNames_givenDishId(10);
var anotherThing = thing.ToList();
MessageBox.Show(anotherThing.ElementAt(0).ingredientname);
```

@Sharag & marc_s: got this older method to work too!! Much appreciated. A few items to note for others new to using this: I needed this line:

```
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
```

alsoI needed to explicitly set the @dishid as an int in this line or it would be considered an Object by the compiler:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dishid", Convert.ToInt32(aValue));
```

Comment: Try doing `.ToArray()` rather than `.AsEnumerable()`.

Comment: @Enigmativity: If you post this as an answer, I will mark it as the answer.

Comment: I've added an answer as per your suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest thing to do is replace the `.AsEnumerable()` with `.ToArray()` in the following code:

```
 var thing = dbContextCreateMenu.ingredientNames_givenDishId(10);
 var anotherThing = thing.AsEnumerable();
    foreach (var subthing in anotherThing)
```

Make it:

```
 var thing = dbContextCreateMenu.ingredientNames_givenDishId(10);
 var anotherThing = thing.ToArray();
    foreach (var subthing in anotherThing)
```

The thing with `.AsEnumerable()` is that it is a fairly weak operator and does nothing more than perform a casting operation.

This is the decompiled source from "System.Core, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089":

```
[__DynamicallyInvokable]
public static IEnumerable<TSource> AsEnumerable<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source)
{
  return source;
}
```

It doesn't actually do anything to force execution of your query.

Calling `.ToArray()` does force the execution.

The other alternative is calling `.ToList()`. I don't advocate doing this unless you know that you want to change the membership of the list. The performance of each is virtually identical. Both `.ToArray()` and `.ToList()` add elements to an array that initially begins with 4 elements and then doubles the capacity each time the current capacity is reached. However, a call to `.ToArray()` will be more memory efficient as the last thing that it does before returning the array is truncate the buffer. So a `List<T>` of 1,025 items will internally contain 2,048 members, but a `T[]` of 1,025 elements will contain only 1,025 items - the buffer used in its construction of 2,048 members is immediately available for garbage collection.

Answer (score 2):

On C# side, you can access using reader, datatable, adapter.

Example code for data reader is presented below

```
SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);

command = new SqlCommand("TestProcedure", connection);
command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
connection.Open();

reader = command.ExecuteReader();

List<Test> TestList = new List<Test>();

Test test;

while (reader.Read())
{
    test = new Test();
    test.ID = int.Parse(reader["ID"].ToString());
    test.Name = reader["Name"].ToString();

    TestList.Add(test);
}
```

Comment: I made this work with a few minor adjustments! Thanks! I am hoping to do this with LINQ still yet. Tried posting my new code in this box, but it was too long.

Answer (score 1):

I am no expert on LINQ, but if u want old way which always worked, its here:

```
List<String> lt = new List<string>();    
     try{

         if (con.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Closed)
              con.Open();
               cmd.CommandText = qr;\\the query 
                SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                adp.Fill(dt);
             for(int i=0;i<dt.Rows.Count;i++)
               {lt.Add(dt.Rows[i][0].toString());}
            }
            catch (SqlException exc)
            { MessageBox.Show(exc.Message);  }
```

Comment: I got a compiler error on the "dt" of "var rows in dt" saying that it was not an enumerable type. Perhaps there is still some adjustment I can make.